# NMOS transistor in layout

Tags: layout

Can somebody please describe the way that NMOS transistor layers:

1. DIFF
2. POLY1
3. NIMP
4. PIMP

are related to the cross section of it?

[image]

Comment: Do you know what DIFF, NIMP, and PIMP are abbreviations for? Do you know what POLY is? Your question seems to be very broad, can you be more specific?

Comment: https://www.slideserve.com/thane/chapter-5-elements-of-physical-design

Comment: Smells like homework to me. That said, it's a bit of a trick question as there is no P-implant in the diagram. I leave up to the OP to figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layers that you list look like abbreviations from a CAD system  as such they mean what they are defined to mean within the technology description defined for that process.

However if I had to take a stab at this:-

1. DIFF is diffusion the whole lightly doped yellow area that forms the substrate.
2. POLY1 is the Polysilicon area which forms the black bit the gate.
3. NIMP N+ type implant is the source and drain regions colored purple on your diagram.
4. PIMP Would be P+ implant which would be used for P channel transistor source and drain this is not shown on your diagram.

Comment: The substrate is not diffused, it is doped when the silicon ingot is pulled. This gives uniform doping through the thickness of the wafer.